# Start a .py file in windows command line

Tags: python

Here is my situation:

```
D:\Python27\python.exe
D:\Python27\search\file.py
```

But `file.py` takes some arguments to start

```
file.py -a searchFunction=dfs
```

How can I open this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umm, add the arguments?

Assuming you're on windows, go Start -> Run -> cmd

Then in the terminal you can type:

`D:\Python27\python.exe D:\Python27\search\file.py -a searchFunction=dfs`

Answer (score 2):

ummm

```
D:\Python27\python.exe D:\Python27\search\file.py -a searchFunction=dfs
```